# Bootstrap Popover plugin: not displaying the html content properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-popover

The Bootstrap Popover plugin is not displaying the HTML content properly.

I have a button inside the popover and when clicking that button I need to perform some action. When I add the `onclick` function on the button, the button disappears from the popover.

Also, the button and popover are randomly generated so I can't use the jQuery onclick.

Can anyone help me with why the button is not displayed if I add an `onclick` function in the bootstrap popover?

```js
$('.popover-menu').popover({
  'html': true,
  'placement': 'top',
  'trigger': 'manual',
  'animation': false,
  'container': 'body',
  'template': '<div class="popover popover-menu-wrapper"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div></div>',
  'content': function () {
    var content = $(this).attr('id');
    return $("#" + content + "Popover").html();
  }
});
```

Comment: 'Also, the button and popover are randomly generated so I can't use the jQuery onclick.' Yes you can - use a [delegated event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have tried the same but the problem is that when ever I try to add some additional parameter to the html button it disappear from the popover.

Comment: Adding  'sanitize': false in the config solve my problem.